# Calendar Time millisecond in Java

Tags: java

Why this appends?

```
Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")); 
Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+2")); 

System.out.println(c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
System.out.println(c2.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+":"+c2.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

System.out.println(c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis());
```

Output:

```
18:12
20:12
0 !!!!!!!!
```

I have 2 divfferent Calendar obj, one set on UTC timezone, one on GMT+2.
When i print the hours and seconds are different but why this difference (c1.getTimeInMillis() - c2.getTimeInMillis()) is 0???

Comment: RTFM: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29   it returns milliseconds in UTC. So it doesn't matter WHAT timezone you set, it'll be in UTC. so your two objects are going to have essentially identical UTC times and a difference of 0.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: just as soon as people actually try reading the docs BEFORE they come ask questions that are trivial to find the answer for.

Comment: Hey, you're the one reading the nastiness into it. I actually meant it as Read The Friendly Manual...

Answer (score 1):

The two calendars are set to be the same instance in UTC time -- they are the same. However, they are set to different timezones, which the reporting function, `get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` uses to give you the hour in local time (i.e. affected by the timezone). So, your comparison is against the instant, which is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say it is 2PM in Seattle.  This means that it's 4PM in Indianapolis.  Is the difference in the current time between these places 2 hours, or 0 hours?  I'm pretty sure it's 0, else there has been a tear in the space-time continuum :)

The technical reasoning behind this is as MarcB commented above:

From the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTimeInMillis%28%29

> Returns this calendar's current time as UTC milliseconds from the epoch.

It doesn't matter what timezone is used to construct the Calendar object, it'll be in UTC. so your two objects are going to have an identical UTC instant in time, and the difference between them will be 0.

Comment: Because it doesn't explain why java behaves this way, which is the basis of the question. It's a programming question, not philosophy.